# javaで日付の有効性チェックを行いたい

Tags: java, 正規表現

`^((19|20)\\d\\d)([- /.])(0[1-9]|1[012])([- /.])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$`

現在JAVAで日付有効性チェックソースコード作成しております。
しかし、ソースコードは
1990 01 01 
1990-01-01 
上の条件も全部trueです。
私は1990-01-01 ＜＜この形式だけtrueにしたいです。
ただ1990-01-01　＜＜この形式だけtrueにしたいだったらどうすればいいですか。

`^((19|20)\\d\\d)([- /.])-(0[1-9]|1[012])([- /.])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$`
上みたいに挑戦した事もありますができませんでした。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/81031

Answer (score 2, accepted):

日付の有効性チェックを自作することはあまりお勧めできません(「車輪の再発明」になるので)。`commons-lang`の`DateUtils`などを利用した方がいいと思います。

```
try {
    DateUtils.parseDateStrictly("1990 01 01", new String[] {"yyyy-MM-dd"});
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // 日付として有効ではない場合の処理を実装
}
```